# Insertar salto de línea escribiendo en un txt (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter

Como puedo insertar un salto de línea :

```
archi.write(svnombreRP.get())
```

Lo hago de la siguientes maneras y no me funciona:

No funciona

```
archi.write(svnombreRP.get()'/n')
```

No funciona

```
archi.write(svnombreRP.get()/n)
```

No funciona, me imprime la variable y /n seguido

```
archi.write(svnombreRP.get()+'n')
```

No funciona

```
archi.write(svnombreRP.get()+/n)
```

Comment: pues en la siguiente linea imprime el salto print("\n")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El Carácter de escape para un salto de línea es `\n`  que sería lo que tendrías que concatenar a tu cadena para tener el salto.
[cadenas-de-caracteres](http://docs.python.org.ar/tutorial/2/introduction.html#cadenas-de-caracteres)

```
archi.write(svnombreRP.get() +'\n')
```